# Считать кириллицу из .xlsm в C#

Tags: c#, кодировка, io

Изначально моя программа принимала на вход CSV файл сохранённый в Unicode и нормально считывала с него данные, но пришлось перейти на Excel и вот тут я столкнулся с проблемой отображения содержимого файла .xlsx
Что я делал:

```
Encoding win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
string whole_file = File.ReadAllText(OpenCSVFile(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

- Поигрался с предложенными кодировками, Unicode, UTF-8, но результат один и тот же, отображаются некорректные символы.
- На одном форуме нашёл `Encoding.Default()`, но это решение не помогло

Данные выглядят следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Понимаю, что проблема в кодировке, но решить проблему не удалось.
Буду рад услышать советы и рекомендации.

Программа отлично работала с CSV, но к сожалению часто CSV файлы "ломаются",съезжают строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сслылка на файл из примера** [https://wdho.ru/in0i/ex2007only_data&break.xlsx](https://wdho.ru/in0i)

Comment: Нужен пример такого файла.

Comment: @Bulson я добавил файл в основное сообщение. Прошу помощи

Comment: xlsx - это зазипованный файл. Хотелось бы видеть метод `OpenCSVFile`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov '''OpenCSVFile''' это мой метод в котором находится OFD и который возвращает **путь**, ничего такого) но если всё же нужно, то скину. У меня открывались csv-файлы, а вот Excel уже не хочет нормально считываться.

Comment: Ещё раз: xlsx - это не _текстовый_ файл, а _бинарный_. Он зазипован (zip).

Comment: Как способ изврата, можно экспортнуть в HTML и распарсить. CSV для интеграции с экселем - вообще не вариант, он со времен MS Office'97 кривой. Другой вариант, использовать сам эксель програмно через `Office.Interop.Excel`, примеры гуглятся в больших количествах. Но лучше всего ответ, опубликованный ниже.

Comment: По поводу кодировки, откройте файл в Notepad++ и подберите там правильную кодировку, 99.99% - это не 1251.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, что то не сразу догнал, я просто перепишу небольшой участок кода. Я думал обойдётся меньшей кровью, но нет)

Comment: @aepot спасибо, я так и решил делать, только без изврата))) Office.Interop.Excel и доволен им, вариант из ответа не использовал, но рано или поздно попробую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использовал [EPPlus 5](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus).
Ставим пакет [image: пакет]

Код в форме такой

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._buttonOpen.Click += ButtonOpen_Click;
    }

    private void ButtonOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_openFileDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = OfficeOpenXml.LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(_openFileDialog.FileName)))
        {
            var page = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Page1"];
            for (int row = 1; row <= page.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 1; col <= page.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine($"Строка: {row}, столбец: {col}," +
                        $" {page.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString().Trim()}");
                }
            }
        }

        _textBoxOutput.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Работает это так
[image: пример работы]

Comment: спасибо. У меня просто уже программа была полностью написана, с этим расширением придётся всё переписать :) Но если что я приму к сведению эту библиотеку, если бы я про неё знал сразу бы её использовал, то что надо. Но пока я попробую решить проблему с кракозябрами

Comment: @proritsatel а чем вы пользовались чтоб прочитать файл? `string whole_file = File.ReadAllText(...)` это прочтет только текст, а как оттуда вы выдергиваете нужную информацию?

Comment: @Bulson он экспортированный CSV читает, и у него некоторые символы идут мимо кодировки.

Comment: @Bulson я читал файл .csv. Спасибо просто решил переделать начальную часть, это не так и запарно получится.